# Query optimization: apply SELECT, PROJECT before JOIN

Tags: sql, query-optimization, relational-algebra

I am learning about query optimization. In general, applying PROJECT and SELECT before JOIN will give you better performance. My question is:

Are there any cases that applying SELECT operation before applying JOIN operation or applying PROJECT operation before applying JOIN operation will be better?

Thanks for any response.

Comment: What is PROJECT operation? What SQL product are you using?

Comment: @AndriyM: `PROJECT` is relational parleance for taking a subset of the columns,; `RESTRICT` is taking a subset of the rows. See for instance:  http://www.cs.scranton.edu/~mccloske/courses/cmps340/rel_alg_intro_lec.html

Comment: Query optimization is a tricky business, dependent on many factors.  If using the project/select/restrict impedes the use of indexes, then "yes", applying them first could cause worse performance.

Comment: Thanks wildplasser for clarifying the question.

Comment: Gordon Linoff: Thanks for your response. Could you explain more about this? I still don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Pushing selections" down is one of the basic optimization strategies which can reduce the amount of I/Os  that need to be done .

For instance , a  selection containing a sargable predicate, if pushed under the join , will effectively reduce the  number of I/Os by reducing the number of  tuples in the outer relation (Nested Loops Join requires  `|R|+|R|*|Q|`  I/Os) .

The main downside of pushing selections down is the situation in which the existing indices on the original relation cannot be used. The decision of whether to push or not is done in conjunction with the choice of the join method.

Similarly, you can "push" a projection down if it retains the attributes needed for the join.